# Hotkeys and slider for brightness don't work

Tags: nvidia, shortcut-keys, 15.10, brightness, backlight

I have an Intel processor with no graphics and Nvidia GTX980M with Nvidia driver. I just installed Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 and everything works fine except for the brightness controls.

Changing both from Fn hotkeys and from slider, the brightness of the screen remains the same (probably set to the max value).

I tried to add `acpi_backlight=vendor` as parameter of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` like other posts suggest, but this just deleted brightness slider making hotkeys do nothing.

The command `ls /sys/class/backlight` returns `acpi_video0`

Values for `brightness` and `max_brightness` in `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0` are both set to `10`.

Does anyone know where is the problem?